# How to programmatically set the title text color in the OSX Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, colors

I have a script that runs in a tabbed terminal window which will periodically update the tab's title with some text using:

```
printf '\e]1;Some Text\a'
```

This works great, but I'd like to take to take it a step further and colorize the text under certain conditions.  I can set the actual terminal's text color by doing something like:

```
printf '\e[31mRed Text'
```

but, I can't quite figure out how to make this apply to the tab's title.

I guess there are really two questions here:

1. Is it even possible to change the color of the title text in the window/tab (specifically for OSX's Terminal)?
2. If it is possible, what sort of magic is necessary to make this happen from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your terminal emulator has to recognize that `printf '\e]1;Some Text\a'` is a request to change the text in title bar (or tab) to `Some Text`. Most do.

It would also be up to the terminal emulator to treat any other escape sequences as something other than literal text to display. That is, there is nothing you can do to *force* the title text to be a different color; you can only read the documentation for your terminal emulator to see what you can *request* it to do.